# Order of Growth for f(n) and g(n)

Tags: big-o

I'm studying Big Oh notation and can't figure out this question:

```
For this pair of functions, f(n) and g(n), is f o(g), θ(g), 
or g is o(f) and why?

f(n) = n^10
g(n) = (n+2)^10
```

g(n) is definitely bigger than f(n) but not by much, so I'm guessing f(n) is o(g) because it describes a tighter bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f belongs to big-theta(g) if and only if f is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically.

This may sound a bit hard to understand but in short this means that there exist positive constants k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub> and number n<sub>0</sub> such that for all n > n <sub>0</sub> the following inequality holds: k<sub>1</sub> * g(n) <= f(n) <= k<sub>2</sub> * g(n). in your case it is not hard to think of such constants take for instance k<sub>1</sub>=1/2 and k<sub>2</sub>=2 it is not hard to find n<sub>0</sub>.

Therefor f belongs to big-theta g.

Also take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) for the formal definitions.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. What is the value of n<sub>0</sub> in this case?

Comment: Many values will do you don't have to be strict. To find the most strict solve the two inequalities and choose the greater of the two values.  If you are lazy to do so,  100^100 will definitely do

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Big O notation - coefficients don't matter, so theta(f(n)) = theta(g(n))

Comment: Where is the coefficient?

Comment: Think about it this way, (2n)^10 vs (n)^10, here there's a clear coefficient that doesn't matter. This coefficient scales the first function much more than +2 would for almost all inputs. The important part is that the +2 does not effect *how fast* the function grows. It still grows at a rate of n^10 (both of them do)